# Xamarin Studio Tasky could not find MonoTouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, macos-sierra

When trying to build Tasky in Xamarin Studio on macOS Sierra

`The type or namespace name 'MonoTouch' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

This occurs in the file `Main.cs` inside of `TaskyiOS`

Comment: MonoTouch is the old name for Xamarin.iOS.  It's been deprecated for a while now.  It sounds like you have an old copy of Tasky, or maybe Xamarin needs to update their samples.

Comment: How do you stop the build from using the old MonoTouch namespaces? We already updated to the unified API ages ago but now it's doing this..

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using an old version on the app and I got an updated version through [their Github repository.](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples)